# How to solve error 91 in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I encountered this error when i ran this code on my search button. Below is my code. Thank You.

```
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

    Private Sub txtsearch_Click()

        If IsNull(Searchbar) = False Then

             Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[PONumber]=" & Searchbar

             Me!Searchbar = Null

             If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then

                   MsgBox "No record found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sorry"

                    Me!Searchbar = Null

             End If

         End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep the recordset:

```
Private Sub txtsearch_Click()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    If IsNull(Me!Searchbar.Value) = False Then
         Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
         rs.FindFirst "[PONumber]=" & Me!Searchbar.Value
         If rs.NoMatch Then
             MsgBox "No record found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sorry"
         Else
             Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
         End If
         Me!Searchbar.Value = Null
     End If

     Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, when i click on the search bar, it does not show me the record i want in the subform

Comment: No, because you didn't mention anything in that regard. See edited answer setting `Bookmark`.